# Lines in HTML source code added automatically

Tags: php, html, utf-8, meta-tags

I am working on a website that was build in php. Now i am redesign it. When I open any of the website pages in the editor, two lines are automatically added, one on top and the other at the bottom of the page:

```
<!-- Added by HTTrack --><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" /><!-- /Added by HTTrack -->
```

Is this harmful? Please tell me why this appears, and how I can get rid of this.

```
</body>
<!-- Added by HTTrack --><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" /><!-- /Added by HTTrack -->
</html>
```

```
<?php include_once 'conn.php' ?>
<!doctype html>
<!-- Added by HTTrack --><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" /><!-- /Added by HTTrack -->
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
```

Comment: HTTrack is a software that copy a website, the files that you are using were copied by this software and the software added some missed meta tags.

Comment: Apparently it is added by HTTrack See https://www.httrack.com/
and no it isn't harmful

Comment: PS, if you are editing files obtained by HTTracker.. then you are not editing the sites PHP files, you are only editing the HTML code that the PHP files produce.

Comment: But sir i did not copy this website. I just open a single file in editor, but now that line is inserted in all files of website.Thaks sir for information

Comment: So maybe the developer before you used HTTrack